# FLATTEN with TABLE_DATE_RANGE

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a range of tables in a dataset and need to query all of them while FLATTENing one of the repeated records. For example, a query like the following works fine:

```
 SELECT
   date,
   customDimensions.value AS customDimension,
   hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath
FROM
   (FLATTEN( [<projectId>:<datasetId>.ga_sessions_20130910] ,
   customDimensions)) 
WHERE
   hits.page.pagePath CONTAINS '/helmets' 
   AND customDimensions.index IN (1,2,3)
```

However, I am having trouble FLATTENing while using table wildcards. Can someone help me out with the syntax? Is it possible to use FLATTEN with TABLE_DATE_RANGE?

```
SELECT
   date,
   customDimensions.value AS customDimension,
   hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath
FROM
   (FLATTEN (TABLE_DATE_RANGE ([<project>:<dataset>.ga_sessions_],
   TIMESTAMP('2013-09-10'),
   TIMESTAMP ('2014-06-10'))),
   customDimensions) 
WHERE
   hits.page.pagePath CONTAINS '/helmets' 
   AND customDimensions.index IN (1,2,3)
```

Thanks, 
Shayan

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to reference manual, the FLATTEN syntax is:

```
...(FLATTEN ([project_name:]datasetId.tableId, flattenField))..
...(FLATTEN (subselect_clause, flattenField))..
```

Based on this, I would try putting a subselect clause within the FLATTEN statement like so:

```
SELECT
date,
customDimensions.value AS customDimension,
hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath
FROM
FLATTEN(
(SELECT date, customDimensions, hits FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE ([<project>:<dataset>.ga_sessions_],
TIMESTAMP('2013-09-10'),TIMESTAMP ('2014-06-10')))
, customDimensions)
WHERE
hits.page.pagePath CONTAINS '/helmets' 
AND customDimensions.index IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Already explored this option, but was hoping FLATTEN worked with TABLE_DATE_RANGE for cleaner queries. I suppose it's not possible as of yet. I'll file for a feature request.

Comment: I agree - that would be nice. +1 on the feature request ;-)

Comment: The solution doesn't work.  I got this error message: Error: Field 'customDimensions' not found.

Comment: You can plus one on this feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=106

Comment: The answer is probably to move to using standard SQL. I moved back to legacy because it had some functions that standard doesn't yet have. However I've found that theses were simple enough to implement with user-defined functions: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me..

```
SELECT
   date,
   customDimensions.value AS customDimension,
   hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath
FROM
   (FLATTEN (SELECT * FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE ([<project>:<dataset>.ga_sessions_],
   TIMESTAMP('2013-09-10'),
   TIMESTAMP ('2014-06-10'))),
   customDimensions) 
WHERE
   hits.page.pagePath CONTAINS '/helmets' 
   AND customDimensions.index IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.